# How to setup XAMPP such that a website's root is in /html and not /

Tags: php, xampp, virtualhost

How to setup XAMPP such that a website's root is in /html and not /

In other words, I would like to set up XAMPP so when I open up a project, say C:/xampp/.../myproject, [where its contents are folders /html, /views, and /includes] the server will output the index file within the folder /html, but the URL will not say /myproject/html, but rather just /myproject [omitting any mention of retrieving the index file from the html folder.]

Hope that was specific enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set up a virtual host for this you can find VirtualHosts apache configuration here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/. Another way is to use Apache's mod_rewrite to internally redirect all requests to your folder to you html directory. You can add the following to an .htaccess file in the root of your project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^$ html/ [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) html/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing the .htaccess method [because it seemed easier] and, when implemented, I received this error [500] when browsing to the root.

Comment: "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22 Server at localhost Port 80"

Comment: can you post what is last error in your error logs it is most probably in c:\xampp\apache\logs?

Comment: [Fri Jan 17 00:37:07.471123 2014] [core:error] [pid 3112:tid 1772] [client 127.0.0.1:64171] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/jeromie/

Comment: Do you use links to your JS and CSS as /html/css or /html/js?

Comment: I currently do not have css or js files right now. But when i do, it would be under /includes which is the same level as the /html folder.

Comment: So you cannot do what you want this way and .htaccess will not be usable. This needs all your public accessible content to be under html folder to work.

Comment: Also do you have index.html or index.php in your html directory?

Comment: This is my filing structure. And it should work as many projects that implement MVC can look something like this.
http://cdn.imghack.se/images/d7ee994ea2bd1d27d55f1d16923c8eab.png

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to use a framework when designing the front-end and navigation of your PHP web application. Now since I am also an intermediate PHP developer, I am not sure which PHP-specific frameworks will help you achieve this. There are plenty of open-source PHP frameworks available on the web. Visit [PHP Frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) for more information.

I am currently making use of the DurandalJS JavaScript framework, and have achieved this functionality for my PHP web application successfully. You can find out more about DurandalJS over [here](http://www.durandaljs.com). I also know of another framework, Hot Towel SPA that helps us do the same thing. However Hot Towel SPA is designed for ASP.NET applications; if you can replicate this in PHP, then well and good.

Hope this helps.